# Why are the following logs logging different values (array loop)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What we want to do is to use a single schema create a new array (with the values of `arrObj`:

```
 const arrObj = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'aaa'
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'bbb',
}]

const schema = [{
  name: 'id',
  value: ''
}, {
  name: 'title',
  value: ''
}]

const finalArrObj = []

arrObj.forEach(eachArrObj => {
  const eachArr = [...schema] // copy array without pointing to the original one
  eachArr.forEach(field => {
    field.value = eachArrObj[field.name]
    console.log('1: ' , field) // correct value
  })
  console.log('2: ', eachArr) // the objects are all the same
  console.log('3: ', eachArr[0].value) // the object here is correct
  finalArrObj.push(eachArr)
})
```

For some reason, the values in console log number `2` logs an array with the same object. Console log number `3` logs the correct object.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Live example: https://codepen.io/sky790312/pen/KmOgdy

**UPDATE:**

Desired result:

```
[{
  name: 'id',
  value: '1'
}, {
  name: 'title',
  value: 'aaa'
}],
[{
  name: 'id',
  value: '2'
}, {
  name: 'title',
  value: 'bbb'
}]
```

Comment: your copy is not a copy, because the inner objects are linked together. please add what you like to get.

Comment: @NinaScholz Please see my UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map new objects by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for `schema`, before assigning values to it.

```
schema.map(a => Object.assign({}, a, { value: o[a.name] }))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            take empty object for
                                  ^                         assingning values of a and
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   only the value of a property
```

```js
const arrObj = [{ id: 1, title: 'aaa' }, { id: 2, title: 'bbb' }],
     schema = [{ name: 'id', value: '' }, { name: 'title', value: '' }],
     finalArrObj = arrObj.map(o => 
         schema.map(a => Object.assign({}, a, { value: o[a.name] }))
     );

console.log(finalArrObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: how can I add if statements while the values are being assigned to the new array/objects?

Comment: do you have an example what you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the inner object also, replace this

```
const eachArr = [...schema];
```

with this

```
const eachArr = schema.map((e)=>{ 
   return Object.assign({}, e);
})
```

Comment: what's wrong with "const eachArr = [...schema];" ?  is that still point to same address ?

Comment: No, but the objects in it, they are pointing to the same reference, that's why you have to copy them as well.